# Disable a button if no save is needed

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

With previous versions of Knockout, it was possible to deactivate a button if nothing needed to be saved like this:

```
<button type="submit" data-bind="enable: CanSave">Save</button>
```

With the 2.2.0 version, this result in an undefined error on this 'CanSave'.

Any replacement?

Thanks.

Comment: `CanSave` was never part of KO. You've must been using some third party plugin/extension which was provided that functionality...

Comment: You are right. This is part of upshot and I read that upshot is officially dead. Any idea how can I disable a save button if applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On of the ways to determine if something needed to be saved is to use dirty flag. It keeps track of changes in view model.

Such functionality is not part of knockout, but can be easily added. See implementation of dirty flag here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the canSave functionality yourself for example by using the validation library for KO.

I have made a little Convention over configuration library for KO, with my lib the syntax would look like

```
<button data-name="save">Save</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ajnj/

Without my lib

```
<button data-bind="click: save, enable: canSave">Save</button>
```

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions

Comment: Thank you very instructive but this time I'll go with the suggestion from Alex with the dirty flag.